# Mongoid has many relationship with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am using rails with mongoid

I have a model with a scope

```
Class Attachment
  scope :documents, -> { where(is_document: true) }
```

I want to create a relationship on another model with this specific scope.
The following is not working it gets all the attachments not just documents

```
has_many :documents, class_name: 'Attachment', foreign_key: :user_id do
  -> { documents }
end
```

And this gives me an error

```
has_many :documents, -> { documents }, class_name: 'Attachment', foreign_key: :user_id
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a much better way to do this - just create different types of documents and store them in the same collection though inheritance:

```
class Attachment
  include Mongoid::Document
end

class Document < Attachment
end
```

Remember that Mongodb is document based and you can store many types of documents in a single collection.

This lets you dump that smelly boolean and scope as you can query `Document.all` instead.

Setting up the association is also really straight forward:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :documents
end
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/nviennot/nobrainer/issues/115#issuecomment-69365980

```
has_many :documents, class_name: 'Attachment', foreign_key: :user_id, :scope => -> { from_true_document }
```

In Attachment class do this:

```
Class Attachment
  def self.from_true_document
    where(is_document: true)
  end
```

Comment: Invalid association option :scope for association
Valid options are: [:after_add, :after_remove, :as, :autosave, :before_add, :before_remove, :dependent, :foreign_key, :order, :primary_key, :class_name, :inverse_of, :validate, :extend], make sure you use only those. (Mongoid::Errors::InvalidRelationOption)